# Storing values in a Dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I want to get numbers from the keyboard (or from a file: ./a.out < file) and store them in an array. The idea is that the length of the array is unknown.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* newElem(){
int* elm= malloc(sizeof(int));
  if (elm == NULL) {
    printf("\nError: memory allocation failed.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
return elm;
}


int main(){
int *array,x,size,i=0;

    while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 ){

        array= newElem();
        array[i]=x;
        i++;

    }

size=i;
free(array);
printf("size=%d",size);


return(0);
}
```

Why does this crash after I enter:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
array= newElem();
```

is going to overwrite the existing pointer (memory) every time. so, `array[i]` becomes invalid, which essentially is an access out of bounds which in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to use [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) to re-size the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
array= newElem();
array[i]=x;
i++;
```

newElem() always return int[1] and you tried to access [n]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that an array is a sequence of **consecutive** addresses.
This means that if the address of the first element is 0, the address of the second element will be 1, and the next 2, so on...

When you say `x[10]` in C, you are in fact saying `*(x + 10)`, which means "from the first element (0), advance 10 addresses (+ 10), and give me the **contents** (* operator) of that address as an int.

So you see, there is a mathematical relation between elements, they are all next to each other in memory.

Now, to your code...

When you call `array= newElem();`, your pointer `array` points to the newly allocated address. However, any previous address `array` was pointing to **before** is **lost**, which is causing both your unexpected behavior and memory leak.

When you first call `array= newElem()`, lets suppose an integer is allocated at the address `A`, and the next time a new integer is allocated at the address `B`, and so on...

On first iteration, with `i = 0`:

```
while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 ){

    array= newElem();
    // array points to A

    array[i]=x;
    // array[0] = x
    // or *(array + 0) = x
    // same as *(array) = x

    i++;
    // i = 1
}
```

Now you will MOST LIKELY have an error (`i = 1`):

```
while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 ){

    array= newElem();
    // address A is lost, and now array points to B

    array[i]=x;
    // array[1] = x; -> likely an ERROR
    // *(array + 1) = x

    i++;
    // i = 2

}
```

On the second iteration, you try to access the address **NEXT TO** the new address `array` points to, which would be C, that is why you get a violation.

Your code does not maintain a relationship between the elements of the array, you are essentially creating single integers in every iteration, and then trying 
to access then but you are actually accessing invalid memory addresses.

It is not a very simple concept at first, comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: so basically what I want to do is:  `while( scanf("%d",&x)==1 ){  
        array=realloc( array, sizeof(int) * (i+1));  
        array[i]=x;
        i++;
    }`

Comment: A few problems with that approach. Realloc might move the whole block to another area, then it will copy the values you had in the older block to the new block. If you increase the size by 1, it will copy the whole array at every iteraion. Imagine you have 1000 ints, you risk a chance of copying 9999 items in memory just so you can store the last 1. Morden languages usuallly double the capacity at every expansion. So try and start with an array of 10, then if you need more, expand to 20, then 40 and so on. Read this http://goo.gl/qOt0P9